# Bash does into unexpected recursion when processing expression inside [[

Tags: bash, if-statement, recursion, error-handling, comparison-operators

I am trying to understand the logic of Bash algorithm.

When I tried this, it printed "a":

```
a=a;[ $a == "a" ] && echo $a
```

So far so good. Then I tried the following and it printed "a" again:

```
a=a;[[ $a == "a" ]] && echo $a
```

Now I introduced an error by using arithmetic comparison:

```
a=abc;[ $a -eq "abc" ] && echo $a
```

I got an error message that makes sense:

```
-bash: [: abc: integer expression expected
```

Then I tried to do this with double bracket and got no error, but "abc":

```
a=abc;[[ $a -eq "abc" ]] && echo $a
```

I can sort of explain it (bash is trying to be accomodating), but then I got something that puzzles me. If I do that, I get an error message about recursion:

```
a=a;[[ $a -eq "a" ]] && echo $a

-bash: [[: a: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "a")
```

If I use single brackets, there is no recursion but a reasonable error "integer expression expected":

```
a=a;[ $a -eq "a" ] && echo $a
-bash: [: abc: integer expression expected
```

This is weird. What Bash is trying to do in that "recursion" case with double brackets? I am talking about:

```
a=a;[[ $a -eq "a" ]] && echo $a
-bash: [[: a: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "a")
```

Comment: `[ $a == "a" ]` is *quite* error-prone: `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[` *at all*, and the unquoted expansion on the left-hand side means that the number of words `$a` expands to is unknown (and thus, likewise, whether the result will be a legal argument list for `[`).

Comment: (When I say "`==` isn't guaranteed to work" in `[` -- that's because the only [POSIX-standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) string comparison operator is `=`).

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to coerce `a` into a numeric form. It does this by treating its contents as a variable name to dereference; when the result of this is a loop, you get a "recursion level exceeded" error.

Thus:

```
a=b
b=10
[[ $a -eq 10 ]]
```

...is true.